# Proving that the maximal abelian extension contains all abelian extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, abelian-groups, extension-field, infinite-groups

I have a small exercise I would like to get help with:

> Let $K$ be a field and $K^{ab}$ be the composite of all finite abelian
>   extensions of $K$.
>
> Prove $K^{ab}/K$ is abelian and that if $L/K$ is abelian then $L$ can
>   be embedded into $K^{ab}$ (note that $L$ can be infinite)

**What I tried:**

I think if we let $\{F_{j}\}_{j\in J}$ be all finite abelian extensions
of $K$ then we can define a map 
$$
Gal(K^{ab}/K)\to\Pi_{j\in J}Gal(F_{j}/K)
$$

by taking $\sigma\in Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ to $\sigma'$ that acts as $\sigma|_{Fj}$
on each $F_{j}$, since this map is injective if follows that $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$
can be embedded into $\Pi_{j\in J}Gal(F_{j}/K)$ which is abelian.

So we get that $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a product
of abelian groups and thus abelian.

Is that correct ?

Can someone help me showing second part of the exercise ?
I think it may be possible to use the classification of abelian groups, but I don't see how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a much longer answer prepared, but I think that this should suffice. If you want justification of my argument, I’ll expand this answer.

You’re really asking whether the compositum of all finite abelian extensions of $K$ is equal to the compositum of all abelian extensions of $K$, whether finite or not. But all our extensions are algebraic, and every infinite algebraic extension is the compositum of its finite subextensions. So the compositum of all abelian extensions of $K$ is also the compositum of all finite abelian extensions.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. I think I understand, but I'm not sure about all the details:Every algebraic extension is the composition of all the simple extensions generated by its elements, each of these extensions must be abelian since otherwise we can take two non commuting automorphisms of the Galois group of such simple extension and define then for the the above composition by fixing all other elements. This shows that each such simple extension is in the composition. Is that argument fine? I would also appreciate feedback about the first part of the exercise. Thanks again!

Comment: I see and am disturbed by your mention of a union of Galois groups, which however are not contained in a larger group. I do feel strongly that all of this should be done without talking about the Galois group(s), but just about the fact that any two $K$-automorphisms, of whatever extension field, commute. Feel free to e-mail me, if you like. I can send you the longer treatment, which I discarded from here.

Comment: I tried to correct my answer, I meant the product of the groups instead of the union. Does this seem ok ? I have sent an email for a further discussion, thanks!